# Fresh installation of Apache and Symfony2, error: Container extension "security" is not registered

Tags: apache, symfony

I've got a problem with Symfony2. Because I want to use wincache in Windows 8, I have to install php NTS. So I've installed Apache 2.4.3 from:

http://www.apachelounge.com/download/

and php 5.4.7 NTS. This is configuration of fcgi in httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi .php
    FcgidInitialEnv PHPRC "c:/serwer/php"
    FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 1000
    FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 1000
    FcgidMaxProcesses 15
    FcgidIOTimeout 120
    FcgidIdleTimeout 120
    FcgidWrapper "c:/serwer/php/php-cgi.exe" .php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

I downloaded a Symfony 2.1.2. File config.php from Symfony/web/ says that "Your configuration looks good to run Symfony.". But when I want to run app_dev.php, I've got:

```
LogicException: Container extension "security" is not registered.
```

Comment: nothing to do with Windows. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342406/symfony-2-upgrade-to-2-1-logicexception-container-extension-security-is-not